# How to enable jupyter extension without admin by appropriate way of calling subcommand

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

this question is a representative one for a bunch of questions related to the execution of subcommand of "jupyter" command in Windows.

As I could not get the Admin to install jupyter, I have used `pip install notebook --user` in cmd, and it is not accessible to add jupyter to PATH as well. When using cmd calling "jupyter" or "notebook" would get me **"jupyter/notebook is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"**, so the only way I could call a notebook is by `python -m notebook`, and a `python -m jupyter` would get me the usage of this command, like --help, --version or so.

However, sometimes I might need to add subcommand to jupyter, like `jupyter contrib nbextension install`, but since jupyter is not in the PATH, calling this command directly would give "not recognized" error. Still, it is also not feasible for this command: `python -m jupyter contrib nbextension install`, as it would give me **"Jupyter command 'jupyter-contrib' not found"**.

This issue has troubled me for a while, so I am looking for any help/advice. Perhaps there should be correct way to call subcommand of jupyter following `python -m`?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/github --app-dir dir_with_permission
```

Run in jupyter notebook

```
./jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/github --app-dir dir_with_permission
```

If not, try `which jupyter` and see if you can use the full location